# Rails update one column on multiple records from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag site_update_admin_settings_path, :method => :put do %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <h2>Default Meta Information</h2>
    </legend>
    <% for setting in @settings[:default_meta] %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><%= setting.name %></label>
        <span class="help-block"><%= setting.description %></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="settings[<%= setting.id %>]" value="<%= setting.value %>" />
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <h2>Social Media Information</h2>
    </legend>
    <% for setting in @settings[:social_media] %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><%= setting.name %></label>
        <span class="help-block"><%= setting.description %></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="settings[<%= setting.id %>]" value="<%= setting.value %>" />
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <h2>Analytics Information</h2>
    </legend>
    <% for setting in @settings[:analytics] %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><%= setting.name %></label>
        <span class="help-block"><%= setting.description %></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="settings[<%= setting.id %>]" value="<%= setting.value %>" />
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= submit_tag "Save Settings", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The form ends up with about 10 fields on it that can be edited.  The values for each field maps to the value column for each record in the database.  An example of the database table looks like this:

```
|   id    |         name         |       value        |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |   site_title         |     Page Title     |
|    2    |   twitter_username   |    TwitterHandle   |
```

So basically, the form fields turn into an array of settings that would be held in `params[:settings]`.   The settings param holds key value pairs (id => value) for each field.  The form only updates the value column for a specific row (determined by the id).  I have the form submitting and creating the `params[:settings]` hash but haven't figured out how to get the controller to update the records.  Thoughts?  Please let me know if you need more information as well.

**UPDATE:**
In the params hash, `settings` looks like this:

```
"settings"=>{"1"=>"Website Title", "5"=>"TwitterHandle", "10"=>"FooBar"}
```

The key is the id for the settings table record and the value is what needs to go to the value column in the settings table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params[:settings].each do |id, value|
  Model.find(id).update_attributes(value: value)
end
```

Comment: I added an update to show what the settings part of the params look like.

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks!  Figured, I was over thinking it.